# Using formsets or create multiple model row in django admin

Tags: jquery, django, admin, formset

```
class BoxModel(models.Model):
    box_length = models.FloatField(default=1, help_text=_('Length'))
    box_width = models.FloatField(default=1, help_text=_('Width'))
    box_height = models.FloatField(default=1, help_text=_('Height'))
    box_weight = models.FloatField(help_text=_('Weight'))
    box_volume = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, help_text=_('Volume'))
```

Now I want to create 20 different BoxModels as efficiently as possible using the Django admin interface. I thought about having it as a table where you can tab through all the fields, and then have jQuery add a new row automatically.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the *easiest* way is to build a changelist action that creates 20 blank BoxModels and saves them to the database.

Then, simply add your fields to `ModelAdmin.list_editable` and you will be able to edit all the fields in the list view.

It's definitely the easiest way to accomplish what you're talking about.

Otherwise, build a custom view and modelform with a formset.

Comment: That seems what I'm looking for. How do I add 20 blank boxmodels to the changelist?

Comment: OK I think I know better what you mean:
1. I will create a changelist action, aka a button which creates 20 new empty records and save them to the database.
2. Then the admin page will show these 20 new lines and since I use list_display I can make all (or a limited) fields editable.

Good and easy solution, but I prefer a cleaner way. I will look into making a custom view then.